# Print Spring Schedule information in logs

Tags: spring

I am using Spring @Schedule annotation to schedule a job. Is there any way to print when @Schdeule will start the job? I had enable TRACE level logging however nothing is printed in logs related to schedule. Basically I am looking after how much time my schedule will start -

```
@Service
public class Listener{

    @Log
    private Logger logger;



    @Scheduled(cron = "0 12 16 * * *")
    public void closing() throws Exception {
        //do work here

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve that can be by adding a log in the begin of your method this one will write the date also :

```java
@Service
public class Listener{

    @Log
    private Logger logger;



    @Scheduled(cron = "0 12 16 * * *")
    public void closing() throws Exception {
        logger.info("start of the method");
        //do work here

    }
}
```

Comment: it will print when schedule will run. I am looking to print before schedule run. It seems spring does not put anything in logs when detect @Schedule